# Randomly choosing a preset function in C Programming

Tags: c, stdio

I have a list of different functions in my `main()`:

```
puzzle1(ar); 
puzzle2(ar); 
puzzle3(ar); 
puzzle4(ar); 
puzzle5(ar);
```

I want to randomly pick **only one** of the functions to be called. What should I do to make this happen?

Thank you!

EDIT 1:My functions are all 2D-Arrays

EDIT 2: Got more help from comments.

EDIT 3:After more help, I've done the following:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int rand_output = rand()%5;
int (*fp[5])(char finalpuzzle[NROW][NCOL]);


int main();

char ar[NROW][NCOL];
int x,y,fp=0;

    fp[0]=puzzle1;
    fp[1]=puzzle2;
    fp[2]=puzzle3;
    fp[3]=puzzle4;
    fp[4]=puzzle5;
    (*fp[rand_output])(x,y);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Errors I'm obtaining are :

```
expected declaration specifier or '.....' before 'time'
```

on the `srand` line

```
initializer element is not constant
```

on the `int rand_output` line

```
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

on the `(*fp[rand_output])(x,y)` line

and a bunch of warning that says `initialization from incompatible pointer type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rand()` to select one index and call the function at that index from a list of function pointers.

```
srand(time(NULL));   // called once
int rand_output = rand()%5; 
int (*fp[5]) (int ar[]);

..
..
fp[0]=puzzle1;
fp[1]=puzzle2;
..

(*fp[rand_output])(arr);
```

Or simply in one line:-

```
 int (*fp[5])(int[])={puzzle1, puzzle2,. ...., puzzle5};
```

### A small example code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void op1(int ar[][2]){
    printf("%s","ok");
}
void op2(int ar[][2]){
    printf("%s","ok2");
}
int main(){
    int z[2][2]={{0,1},{2,4}};
    srand(time(NULL));   // called once
    int rand_output = rand()%2; 
    void (*fp[2]) (int ar[][2]);
    fp[0]=op1;
    fp[1]=op2;
    (*fp[rand_output])(z);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention this in my question but my functions all consist of 2D-arrays, does this affect the solution?

Comment: @Raph.: Of course not... :) Just the parameters will be differemt...pass 2d array

Comment: I updated my post with what I've done(its not working)

Sorry for being so clueless with rand() QwQ

Comment: Do the function pointers not need to be passed in with `&` to get their address?  e.g. `fp[0] = &puzzle1`

Comment: Thank you so much @coderredoc, I looked around and saw examples with the `rand()` outside the `main` and thought that was supposed to happen